# Mirror android screen on a spare lcd monitor using usb cable

Tags: screen, screen-mirroring

Can I connect my smartphone running Android 4.2.2 to a spare dell lcd monitor by using a mini usb cable so I can mirror the android screen onto the monitor? Is it possible? Using some app maybe? No desktop is involved. Just a spare lcd.

Comment: Does your monitor have a usb-input which is possible to use as video input? I don't think so.

Comment: You need to be much more specific about the phone and monitor. Model numbers would be helpful. Information and photos of the connections on the monitor would also be helpful. More info, please!

Comment: if your device have MHL capabilities you try buying the cable mentioned in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDS6cP-ViG8

Comment: check out this website for more details on mhl https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2013/08/24/mhl/

Answer (score 1):

Original answer from September 2015:
No, you cannot with a standard USB cable. Depending on the mobile device in question as well as the monitor, you could possibly connect the phone with an [MHL adapter](http://smile.amazon.com/Rankie%C2%AE-Adapter-integrated-Charging-MHL-enabled/dp/B00MY05GNA/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1443534781&sr=8-1&keywords=mhl%20adapter).

Update September 2020:
Five years later and, of course, there are greater options for connecting a mobile device to an external screen. Hoping that everyone is now running newer than Android 4.2.2. and with the use of USB-C for connections, I've been using this [USB-C to HDMI with OTG USB-A and USB-C charging](https://smile.amazon.com/Multiport-Tuwejia-Thumderbolt-Converter-Projection/dp/B07G44M4S3/ref=sxts_sxwds-bia-wc-p13n1_0?cv_ct_cx=usb-c%20hdmi&dchild=1&keywords=usb-c%20hdmi&pd_rd_i=B07G44M4S3&pd_rd_r=8a7e963b-4354-4b62-a4a6-a32ca1b9f24b&pd_rd_w=Mn59a&pd_rd_wg=Yiz7a&pf_rd_p=42e41e42-79c0-42f8-8a91-d71b944e9fa8&pf_rd_r=FM5C7E3MZ8CNMX4M9SCH&psc=1&qid=1600697279&sr=1-1-791c2399-d602-4248-afbb-8a79de2d236f). The important part is the charging feature for two reasons:

1. Some devices will not transmit video without additional power.
2. The adapter will charge the device while it is being used to drive
   an external screen.